# Is there a specific way to deal with const pointer members of a struct in JNA?

Tags: java, struct, mapping, jna

I have the following C structure:

```
typedef struct {
    void           *instance;
    const info_st  *info;
} core_st;
```

Which I map to the following Java Class using JNA:

```
public class core_st extends Structure {

    public Pointer instance;
    public info_st.ByReference info;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("instance", "info");
    }
}
```

I also have the following function taken from a dll:

```
uint32_t open_core(uint32_t core_id, core_st **core);
```

And the relative JNA mapping:

```
int open_core(int core_id, core_st[] core);
```

Finally, I wrote a java program that calls the function this way:

```
core_st[] cores = new core_st[1];
MyLibrary.INSTANCE.open_core(0, cores);
```

The function should populate `cores[0]` members with the result of the "open" operation. In particular, the two fields are two pointers to something else. What happens is that the `void *instance` field is always correctly populated, but the `info` field is always null (a pointer to zero).
If I set the *jna.memory_dump* option to true, any call of `core_st.toString()` returns always the same result:

```
memory dump
[70cb64e7]
[fd7f0000]
[00000000]
[00000000]
```

It looks like the pointer to the *info* structure is not in the memory read by the JNA. The same call, performed by a similar C program, works fine, both pointers are correctly populated.
I also tried to change the *core_st* mapping, just for test purposes:

```
public class core_st extends Structure {

    public long instance;
    public long info;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("instance", "info");
    }
}
```

But I got no differences in the result. *instance* gets a non-null value, and *info* is always null. I am working with a 64bit VM.
I was wondering if the problem could be the *const* modifier of the *info* field? Can the const modifier in a struct field of type pointer change the way the struct is stored in memory?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the `const` modifier in a struct field of type pointer change the way the struct is stored in memory?

The answer is *maybe*, compiler dependent.  More important to your question is how `const` affects the way the field is accessed on the native side.  No matter what you do on the Java side, once you initialize the `info` field of your `core_st` structure, you can not modify it.

And that is why you are seeing what you're seeing here: by defining `public info_st.ByReference info;` you are initializing the `core_st` structure with a pointer to `NULL` and getting the memory address `0x0` stored for that field.  When accessing that field using the API, you can't change the memory address, it's stuck.

You see the same results initializing it as a `long` with the default value (0).

The solution depends on how the API populates that value.  If, on the native side, the `open_core` function assumes that the `info` field is already initialized with a pointer to an allocated structure, and just changes the values at the pointed-to memory, you're all set.  You just need to initialize that field when you first instantiate the structure.

You don't tell me anything about what `*info` points to, so the answer is different depending on whether it's an array of `info_st` structures or a single structure.  If it's a single structure, you have:

```
public class core_st extends Structure {

    public Pointer instance;
    public info_st.ByReference info = new info_st.ByReference();

}
```

This will allocate the appropriate memory here for an `info_st` structure and store the *read-only* pointer in your `core_st` structure.  Depending on the inner workings of `open_core()` (and based on your report that this seems to work on the C side), this may work!

If not, perhaps posting the working C code would help determine whether there's another JNA mapping that would help or if you have to work around it with your own custom dll wrapper function.